# Random using shuffle on laravel blade make unique

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem.

I have this code:

```
  <?php $q =(count($question->answers)/2) - 1;  ?>
    @php ($q = 3)

    @php ($p = 1)
    @for($i=0; $i <=(count($question->answers)/2) - 1; $i++) 

        <?php 

        $match = $question->answers->where('is_key', 0)->shuffle()->toArray();  

        $match = $match->unique();
        dd($match['text']);

        ?>

        <?php $option = $question->answers->where('order', $i)->where('is_key', 1)->first(); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="border: 1px solid  #e8e8e8;">
            <b>{{$p}}.</b> {{$match['text']}} 
        </div>

        <div class="column" style="border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
            <b> {{$p}}. </b>   {{$option->text}} 
        </div>

    </div>

    @php ($p++)
    @endfor
```

So I have these two columns `options` and `match`.

What I need is the match group to be shuffled.

I have tried this so far but when it shuffles sometimes it repeats the same text and some text does not show at all.

E.g.:

When `1 2 3 4` is shuffled it looks like `1 2 1 4` or `1 2 3 3`.

**How do I make the digits unique when shuffled?**

Comment: Does it work if you call `->shuffle()->unique()->toArray()`? What does `$question->answers` contain? (It would be a `Collection` of something, might need an extra param on `->unique()` depending)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **inRandomOrder()**

```
$match = $question->answers->where('is_key', 0)->inRandomOrder()->toArray();
```

Comment: it says Method inRandomOrder does not exist.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using, it does exist see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Just check, and you're right, doesn't work with the relationship in the middle

Comment: No it does not work, I updated my laravel  but still nothing is there another way?

Comment: I think there is another error, you're running the shuffle inside the loop, so basically you're randomizing all answers every time,  try moving this outside of the for loop: $match = $question->answers->where('is_key', 0)->shuffle()->toArray();  also use a different variable here $random = $match->unique();

Comment: @latr.88 `->inRandomOrder()` is a `Query` function (`Builder`), but `$question->answers->where(...)` is a `Collection` at that point, so `->shuffle()` is correct; Laravel version doesn't matter here.

Answer (score -1):

Get all the answers first:

```
$match = $question->answers->where('is_key', 0)->toArray();
```

Then, shuffle it:

```
$match = shuffle($match);
```

Comment: `->shuffle()` is a method on `Collection` that inherently calls the array `shuffle()` method, so this doesn't really change anything.